# 2 Projects in Solution, Only 1 is COM Visible

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have created a solution with 2 projects. I am confused why one of the projects is visible and usable in COM whereas the other is not. I have marked both projects as COM interop. Both are COM visible.

```
Solution
 - ProjectA -> works with CreateObject
 - ProjectB -> Dependent on ProjectA, does not work with CreateObject
```

Is this known behavior?

Edit--

Additional info: Both projects belong to different namespaces. Both have been marked by the ProgId, ComVisible, ClassInterface, ComDefaultInterface and Guid attributes.

Comment: AFAIK, COM doesn't know or care about your VS project structure, only about the types defined (interfaces and co-classes). What happens if you move all types from Project B (the "non-working" one) over to Project A, perhaps one after the other?

Comment: Thank you!!  That solved it. You saved a ton of time and effort. God bless you. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you not interested in finding out the cause? It might happen again...

Comment: stakx: I have been trying to figure it out. still not sure why it happens though. it is happening with every assembly with multiple projects I am creating with vs express 2010.